# Calling Parent to open settings

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react and this is my current structure using material UI

```
<Setting/>
  <Paper className={paperHeight}>
      <Title>Settings</Title>
         <SettingTable />
  </Paper>
```

The setting component returns a button that will open a modal on click. Inside my settingstable component I have an edit button on each row that I would like to simulate the onclick of the Setting component so that the modal opens.

Inside the setting component I have the following to open my modal

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

 const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
 };
```

I don't know what to search to get the answer. I've tried
"Sending props to parent" etc.. but cannot figure out what or how to do it.
If anyone can point me in the right direction,
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As per my understanding, that "Setting" component is rendering "Setting Table" and "Button"(that opens modal).
2. "Setting Table" also have button, that opens same modal. Hence you can use "handleClickOpen" for both scenarios.

   ```
       <Setting>
           <Paper className={paperHeight}>
               <Title>Settings</Title>
               <SettingTable modalHandler={handleClickOpen}/>
           </Paper>
       </Setting>
   ```
3. You can have modalHandler function and pass it as a prop to the child. Link received modalHandler prop to Onclick(edit button) in SettingTable.

   ```
       <SettingTable>
           <Button onclick={props.modalHandler}>Edit</Button>
       </SettingTable>
   ```
4. If "SettingTable" is not rendered by "Setting" component and modalHandler is defined in "Setting" component, I would request you to move modalHandler to the parent, so that it can be shared by its child components.